# has_many through associations in Rails REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

So I have the following association but I can't figure out how to create those records in the API

```
class Website < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :specs
has_many :ads, :through => :specs
end

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :specs
 has_many :websites, :through => :specs
end

class Spec < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :website
 belongs_to :ad
end
```

Now the question is, how would I create this in an API. and I want to make sure when I create join relation, it will show each website with the ads belong to it. in another page, Ads and all websites under that Ad.

Example

```
{
"websites": [
{
"website": {
"id": 1414,
 "name": "google.com"
},
"ads": [
{
"id": 31751,
"title": "amazon"
}, {
"id": 4543,
"title": "hulu"
 }]
```

and for Ads:

```
{
"Ads": [
{
"ad": {
"id": 1414,
"name": "abc"
},
"websites": [
{
"id": 56,
"name": "data.com"
}, {
"id": 23,
"title": "fb.com"
}
```

The good news is that I can show the data in that format, but the part I'm not sure about is how to insert the data into the database so the specs table can have the data about both tables.

Comment: Check the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html. You can created an element with it's associations using "association_attributes" hash and ActiveRecord will handle that.

Comment: could you show the controller

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is interesting, though how I would handle that one website can have many ads and one ad could belong to many websites?

Comment: @arieljuod how can I show and create the data based on the following rule: one website have multiple ads, and one ad has multiple websites.

Comment: Show your controller actions at least, there's a lot of things that can be done with the little code you showed, add some context of the endpoints, the action, it's impossible to give a concrete example.